# Open and closed sets, functional analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I have two questions:
1) Let A be closed subset of normed space. B is a open ball/sphere, with distance delta and center 0. Show that if [image]

Second one is bit diffrent:
 2) Prove that

[image]

is neither closed nor open set is s-space. Could I solve this by using closure?

Answer (score 2):

1) For all $n$, you can find $a_n \in A$ such that $|a_n-x| < \frac{1}{n}$. Then $a_n \to x$ and, since $A$ is closed, $x \in A$.

2) Call $\{ (\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{3^n}, \dots)\}_n=A$. This is not open since its interior is empty (open sets contain some point with irrational coordinates). To show that it is not closed, apply point 1) to $A$ and $x=0$.